# Pandas change of state (decomposition)

Tags: python, pandas, status

I'm trying to find a method of calculate the change of status.

Status: C>B>A

This is the dataset:

| ID | Start |
| --- | --- |
| 1007 | A |
| 1007 | A |
| 1007 | B |
| 1008 | B |
| 1008 | A |
| 1008 | C |
| 1008 | B |
| 1009 | A |
| 1009 | A |

What I would like to do is calculate the number of changes per person.

| ID | Increase | Same | Decrease |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1007 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1008 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 1009 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

Thanks

Comment: Please be more verbose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

    '''
    df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID' : [1007, 1007, 1007, 1008, 1008, 1008, 1008, 1009, 1009],
    'Start' : ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'A']
    })
    '''


def foo(df):

    ID_num = len(pd.unique(df['ID']))

    df_goal = pd.DataFrame({
        'ID': pd.unique(df['ID']),
        'Increase' : [0] * ID_num,
        'Same' : [0] * ID_num,
        'Decrease' : [0] * ID_num
    })

    df_goal.set_index(keys = pd.unique(df['ID']), inplace = True)


    prev_ID = df.loc[0, 'ID']
    prev_start = df.loc[0, 'Start']

    for row in range(1, len(df)):
        tmp_ID = df.loc[row, 'ID']
        tmp_start = df.loc[row, 'Start']

        if tmp_ID == prev_ID:
            if tmp_start > prev_start:
                df_goal.loc[tmp_ID, 'Increase'] += 1

            elif tmp_start == prev_start:
                df_goal.loc[tmp_ID, 'Same'] += 1

            else:
                df_goal.loc[tmp_ID, 'Decrease'] += 1
            
        
        prev_ID = tmp_ID
        prev_start = tmp_start

    
    df_goal.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)
    return(df_goal)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(foo(df))
```

Output :

```
     ID  Increase  Same  Decrease
0  1007         1     1         0
1  1008         1     0         2
2  1009         0     1         0
```